# GCP: Cloud Function app.yaml file for environmental variables formatting issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to deploy a GCP cloud function using the "--env-vars-file" flag and specifying a YAML file to contain the variables. My 'app-dev.yaml' YAML file looks like this:

```
runtime: python37
api_version: '1'
threadsafe: 'true'

env_variables:
  VAR_1: 'var_1_value'
  VAR_2: 'var_2_value'
  VAR_3: 'var_3_value'
```

And my gcloud functions deploy looks like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy my_cloud_function --env-vars-file app-dev.yaml --runtime python37 --trigger-resource my-project.appspot.com --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

Now when I run this command I get back this error:

> gcloud crashed (ValidationError): Expected type  for
>   field value, found {'VAR_1': 'var_1_value', 'VAR_2': 'var_2_value',
>   'VAR_3': 'var_3_value'} (type `<type 'dict'>`)

But according to [this Google example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref) the app-dev.yaml format should be fine.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you provided refers to the `app.yaml` file needed in App Engine and is unrelated.

As per the Cloud Functions doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var), the `.env.yaml` file should have the following format:

```
VAR_1: var_1_value
VAR_2: var_2_value
VAR_3: var_3_value
```

Comment: Thanks - I missed that.

Answer (score 6):

All values must be strings, example:

Wrong value:

> ```
> VAR_1: 3.1416
> ```

Correct value:

> ```
> VAR_1: "3.1416"
> ```